# Place the mouse or cursor on a coordinate

Tags: c#, winforms

I have a PictureBox that loads me a web page, I need to be able to place the mouse or cursor at certain coordinates within the PictureBox. However, I can't do it, use several ways to get the coordinates but once the web page loads, it doesn't work.

```
private void m_WebView_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = "X = " + e.X + " ; Y = " + e.Y;
}

private void m_WebView_MouseMove(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    label1.Text = e.Location.X.ToString();
    label1.Text = e.Location.Y.ToString();
}
```

does not work when loading the web page and event is set

[image]

If I leave the picture box empty, if it shows me the coordinates

I need to locate the mouse in the exact coordinates that I see

Is it possible?

that its i try coords not work

```
var simulator = new InputSimulator();

Point position = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location) +
    new Size(pictureBox1.Location.X / 2 , pictureBox1.Location.Y / 7 );
SetCursorPos(position.X, position.Y);
```

for @Olivier Jacot-Descombes

works the question is how do I locate the coordinates of a and b without having to adjust the values ​​of

```
e.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Size.Height / 7));
```

and start the program close edit open close edit, until I manage to locate them that is my main problem

with this I get coordinates but they don't work

```
  private void m_WebView_MouseMove (object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
        {
            label1.Text = e.Location.X.ToString ();
            label2.Text = e.Location.Y.ToString ();
        }
```

point A = x 106 and Y 106

point B = x 564 and y 225

How do I put those coordinates since they don't work

[image]

Comment: `Location`is the upper left corner, you should add half the `Size` of the picturebox to get the center.

Comment: What are you targetting: Winforms, WPF, ASP..? 
YOU should __always__ __TAG__ your questions correctly so one can see it on the questions page!

Comment: `Point position = PointToScreen(pictureBox1.Location) + new Size(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2 , pictureBox1.Size.Height / 7 );`

Comment: the problem is that this code creates me is the size of the picturebox and I require it is inside the picturebox assign a coordinate

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To place the cursor inside the picture, you must add a fraction of `Size.Width` and `Size.Height` to the location of the picture box.

This works for me

```
Cursor.Position = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(
    new Point(pictureBox1.Size.Width / 2, pictureBox1.Size.Height / 7));
```

Note that this uses the `PointToScreen` method of the picture box instead of the form. Therefore, the location of the picture box is used as a reference automatically. This save us some calculations.

Comment: check the question again, please add what you told me

Comment: I have no idea what you are talking about. What are a and b? It is not clear what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: In the question add the subject of points a and b inside the picture box if you can check it again, I have two locations in the picturebox that I need the mouse to stay there, but I can't do it because the coordinates don't allow to place them because of the characters I can't place it here

Comment: works more simple is that for coords Cursor.Position = pictureBox1.PointToScreen(new Point(171, 80));